# How to change directory by mentioning folder name?

Tags: bash, cd

It's bit annoying to type `cd` every time that I wish to **C**hange **D**irectory and then folder path/name.

So, any ways to avoid it? Without installing any extra stuff..

In case if things are blur: I wanted a replacement for this `prompt> cd folder` with this `prompt> folder`

Comment: you can add this:  alias c=cd   to .bashrc    and run   prompt>source .bashrc   ,In this case, just type: c folder  instead of: cd  folder

Comment: @VishwajithK If it was possible to just type `folder` and you happen to have a folder name with the same name as a command, you'd have a conflict. Which one should "win"?

Comment: See: `man bash | grep autocd`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Yes I dint think of this. Good point
Say I have no folder names conflicting with command names
And, how about `folder_name_is_command_name` would execute the command and `folder_name_is_command_name/` would switch to the directory?

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus; I guess that will be enough

Comment: @Cyrus, This way stdouts the cd and folder name while changing directory. The `q` option did not change directory quietly!


And is there way to get something by hitting enter? Like, I wish that it could change to home directory OR ls files in current directory
Is that possible.

Comment: @Vishwajith.K: I suggest to start a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open your terminal (ctrl + alt + t), type `sudo su` then enter your password
2. (I am using `leafpad` text editor to edit the `.bashrc` file. If you also want to use `leafpad`, install it using `sudo apt-get install leafpad` command, Otherwise, you can use any other text editor as you wish)

   Type the following command  `leafpad ~/.bashrc`  to edit the `.bashrc` file.
3. Add the following command at the end of the file and save the file

   `shopt -s autocd`
4. Update the changes made in the `.bashrc` file with the following command:

   `source ~/.bashrc`

   All Done :)

**OR**

`echo 'shopt -s autocd' >> ~/.bashrc ; . ~/.bashrc` will suffice

Comment: `echo 'shopt -s autocd' >> ~/.bashrc ; . ~/.bashrc` Your solution is too complex.

Comment: @Abelisto  Sorry if it seems too complex, I am just trying to explain what I know but no doubt your answer is the best one. Write it as an answer instead of a comment. It deserves upvotes :)

Comment: It is too short for the answer. There are several remarks BTW: 1) It is unnecessary tu use root privileges to edit the user's `~/.bashrc` 2) aptitude is not the default package manager. `yum install` or `pacman -S` exists in some distributions 3) `vi` installed by default in the most linux distributions